# Nokogiri next elements

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I wrote this code, which should be self explaining:

```
def parse_kapitel(node)
  if node.node_name.eql? 'nummer'
    tmp_kapitel = Kapitel.new
    puts node.next_element['V']
    puts node.next_element.next_element['V']
    puts node.next_element.next_element.next_element['V']    
  end
end
```

My xml:

```
<kapitel>
      <nummer V="1"/>
      <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
      <bis_icd_code V="B99"/>
      <bezeichnung V="Bestimmte infektiöse und parasitäre Krankheiten"/>
      <gruppen_liste>
        <gruppe>
          <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
          <bis_icd_code V="A09"/>
          <bezeichnung V="Infektiöse Darmkrankheiten"/>
          <diagnosen_liste>
            <diagnose>
```

You can see my code is very tedious because I use `next_element` several times.

How can I write the whole thing shorter?

Comment: Do you want a list of diagnoses per ICD chapter/group?

Comment: Your XML example isn't valid. Please use valid examples when asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this?

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.XML <<-eol
<kapitel>
      <nummer V="1"/>
      <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
      <bis_icd_code V="B99"/>
      <bezeichnung V="Bestimmte infektiöse und parasitäre Krankheiten"/>
      <gruppen_liste>
        <gruppe>
          <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
          <bis_icd_code V="A09"/>
          <bezeichnung V="Infektiöse Darmkrankheiten"/>
</kapitel
            eol

doc.xpath("/kapitel//@V").map(&:text)
# => ["1",
#     "A00",
#     "B99",
#     "Bestimmte infektiöse und parasitäre Krankheiten",
#     "A00",
#     "A09",
#     "Infektiöse Darmkrankheiten"]
```

If you want the first three sibling's values of attribute `V`,then do something like this:

```
doc.xpath("/kapitel/*[name(.)='nummer']/following-sibling::*")[0..2].map{|n|n["V"]}
# => ["A00", "B99", "Bestimmte infektiöse und parasitäre Krankheiten"]
```

Comment: Maybe xou can help me with my new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699192/undefined-method-von-for-nilnilclass