# Why do I get "undefined method `von=' for nil:NilClass"?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I wrote this little program:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class Kapitel
  attr_accessor :von, :bis, :bezeichnung
end

class SubKapitel
  attr_accessor :von, :bis, :bezeichnung
end

def parse_file 
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("test.xml"))
  parse_xml(doc)
end

def parse_xml(doc)
  doc.root.elements.each do |node|
    parse_kapitel(node)
  end
end

def parse_kapitel(node)
  if node.node_name.eql? 'nummer'
    tmp_kapitel = Kapitel.new 
  end
  if node.node_name.eql? 'gruppe'
    tmp_kapitel = SubKapitel.new
  end
  tmp_kapitel.von = node['V'] if node.node_name.eql? 'von_icd_code'
  tmp_kapitel.bis = node['V'] if node.node_name.eql? 'bis_icd_code'
end

puts parse_file
```

Using that, I parse this XML file:

```
 <kapitel>
      <nummer V="1"/>
      <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
      <bis_icd_code V="B99"/>
      <bezeichnung V="Bestimmte infektiöse und parasitäre Krankheiten"/>
      <gruppen_liste>
        <gruppe>
          <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
          <bis_icd_code V="A09"/>
          <bezeichnung V="Infektiöse Darmkrankheiten"/>
          <diagnosen_liste>
            <diagnose>
              <icd_code V="A00.-"/>
              <bezeichnung V="Cholera"/>
              <abrechenbar V="n"/>
```

But somehow I get this error:

```
 test.rb:32:in `parse_kapitel': undefined method `von=' for nil:NilClass(NoMethodError)
```

I think the problem is that `von-icd-code` appears twice in the XML document.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please take time to provide valid XML. See my answer below for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(' <kapitel>
      <nummer V="1"/>
      <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
      <bis_icd_code V="B99"/>
      <bezeichnung V="Bestimmte infektise und parasitre Krankheiten"/>FFC3\U+FFA4re Krankheiten"/>
      <gruppen_liste>
        <gruppe>
          <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
          <bis_icd_code V="A09"/>
          <bezeichnung V="Infektise Darmkrankheiten"/>krankheiten"/>
          <diagnosen_liste>
            <diagnose>
              <icd_code V="A00.-"/>
              <bezeichnung V="Cholera"/>
              <abrechenbar V="n"/>')

doc.errors
```

Which outputs:

```
[
    [0] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag diagnose line 12>,
    [1] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag diagnosen_liste line 11>,
    [2] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag gruppe line 7>,
    [3] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag gruppen_liste line 6>,
    [4] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag kapitel line 1>
]
```

If we look at what Nokogiri had to do to fix-up the XML:

```
puts doc.to_xml
```

We see that it added closing tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<kapitel>
      <nummer V="1"/>
      <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
      <bis_icd_code V="B99"/>
      <bezeichnung V="Bestimmte infektise und parasitre Krankheiten"/>
      <gruppen_liste>
        <gruppe>
          <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
          <bis_icd_code V="A09"/>
          <bezeichnung V="Infektise Darmkrankheiten"/>
          <diagnosen_liste>
            <diagnose>
              <icd_code V="A00.-"/>
              <bezeichnung V="Cholera"/>
              <abrechenbar V="n"/></diagnose></diagnosen_liste></gruppe></gruppen_liste></kapitel>
```

It was able to do so correctly for this XML, but in XML that is malformed, or has more complicated data it might not do as well. And, at that point, any subsequent work on the resulting DOM would be suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the method

```
def parse_kapitel(node)
   if node.node_name.eql? 'nummer'
   tmp_kapitel = Kapitel.new 
   end
   if node.node_name.eql? 'gruppe'
   tmp_kapitel = SubKapitel.new
   end
   tmp_kapitel.von = node['V'] if node.node_name.eql? 'von_icd_code'
   tmp_kapitel.bis = node['V'] if node.node_name.eql? 'bis_icd_code'
end
```

The error *undefined method 'von=' for nil:NilClass(NoMethodError)* means at that time `node` name is `'von_icd_code'`, not the `'nummer'`. That's why the `if node.node_name.eql? 'nummer'` evaluated as `false`. But in Ruby local variables are created at parse time,whenever any such assignment statement encountered like, `tmp_kapitel = Kapitel.new`.Now due to `flase` evluation of the `if node.node_name.eql? 'nummer'`,as I said earlier,`tmp_kapitel` local variable holds `nil`,not the object of `Kapitel.new`. And `NilClass` doesn't have any method called `#von`,so the legitimate error thrown to you.

Comment: SO what do i have to change?

Comment: @user2724695 your logic is not clear to me,so what I can say the method `parse_kapitel` you wrote will not work. You have to break it into 2 methods,the logic is with you,but current situation will never get success.